# ng-switch-when preserves previous div space after toggle div

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-switch

Here is my Code :

```
      <div class="wh_box" ng-model="change_div" ng-switch on="change_div">
            <div ng-switch-when="unchanged">
            <ul class="shar_list">
                <li ng-repeat="dish_index in similar">
                    <h2><span>{{dish_index.Dish.name}}</span></h2>
                    <div>
                    <a><img no-image ng-src={{similarfull_image_url+dish_index.Dish.image}} alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li ng-hide="similar.length" class="no_record">No record found</li>
            </ul>
                </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="changed">
                <div class="title">Comments</div>
                <div class = "line"></div>
                <ul class="comment_list">
                    <li ng-repeat="x in comments ">
                        <a><img no-image ng-src="{{profile_img_path.image_url_tiny+x.User.image}}" alt=""></a>
                        <div class="pro_deatil" >
                            <h2> {{x.User.name}} </h2>
                            <p>{{x.CommentDish.comment}}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pro_like" >
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="comment">
                    <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="10" ng-model="comment_data.comment" placeholder="Enter Comment" class="post_txt_area"  ng-blur="blurred()"  ></textarea>
                    <div> <a  ng-click="postComment()" class="event_btn">Comment</a> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My Problem : 
The ng-switch works fine  but when i switch to another div, the Previous div bottom space still visible clearly in the new switched div, Please help me in this issue.

Comment: What do you mean by switching to another page & space of previous page?

Comment: I mean for Div.. When i switch from one div to another div using ng-switch  the previous div space remains..

Comment: Can you please help me in this issue @Shashank :-(

Comment: Can you add a plunkr example? Since this is working fine in my case. Do you have any CSS applied anywhere in the given example?

Comment: i checked same on browser but.. this issue i faced on Android device.. And yes, i applied Css but its not due to CSS, because it happens only once i switched.. then after when i scroll the div it adjust the hieght fine..

Comment: that means at first time when i switched it remains space at bottom..

Comment: Do you mean that issue does not reproduce on laptop browser, its just on mobile device?

Comment: yes.. i'm developing an ionic framework application

Comment: Its been a while, I worked on ionic. So have you inspected your app on android browser? You need to figure it out by inspecting in android on first use.

Comment: I researched about it a lot.. i think it may be due to ng-switch always reserves the previous div scope after switching to next div

Comment: No, `ng-switch` does not work in this way. So you said is not possible because it removes the elements from DOM when any element is not active. Have you inspected the space in mobile device? What is your angular version?

Comment: I'm using Angular Js 1.2.26

Comment: Then in this case, you have to inspect your device browser to see from where that space is coming. https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging